# Using definition, prove that $\lim\frac{3n-2}{4n+1}$ cannot be $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I came upon this question while working on , it is different from the questions I have worked with.

> The sequence is $\frac{3n-2}{4n+1}$. We have to prove that its limit can't be $\frac{1}{2}$.

I approached it by taking that it is equal to 1/2 for a particular n, and by taking right side and left side limits I was going to prove that limit does not exist .

but I am stuck badly , is my approach correct ?

if someone could explain , it would be a great help.

thank you

Comment: *“I was going to prove that limit does not exist”* – the limit does exist (but it is not $1/2$).

Comment: Oh ! no , I took for some n it does not exist , is it different sir @MartinR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not correct. For example, the sequence $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $0$, yet there is no $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $1/n = 0$.

Let's get back to definition. We say that $L$ is the limit of a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ if $$(\forall\varepsilon >0)(\exists n_0\in\mathbb N)(\forall n\in\mathbb N)\ n\geq n_0\implies |a_n-L|<\varepsilon.$$

Now, by negating the above, $L$ *is not* the limit of a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ if and only if $$(\exists\varepsilon >0)(\forall n_0\in\mathbb N)(\exists n\in\mathbb N)\ n\geq n_0\ \text{and}\ |a_n-L|\geq \varepsilon.$$

Now, let $\varepsilon = 1/8$ and $L = 1/2$. We want to check when the condition
$$\left|\frac{3n-2}{4n+1}-\frac 12\right| \geq \frac 18\tag{1}$$ holds. We can rewrite it as $|2n-5|\geq n + \frac 14$ which for $n\geq 6$ is equivalent to $2n-5\geq n + \frac 14$, or $n \geq 5 + \frac 14$. That means that $(1)$ is true for all $n\geq 6$.

We conclude that for $\varepsilon = \frac 18$ and for every $n_0\in\mathbb N$, letting $n = n_0+6$, we have $n\geq n_0$ and $(1)$ is true for $n$. Thus, $L = \frac 12$ is not the limit of the given sequence.

Comment: that was the answer I was looking for , thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0):

That the expression is equal to $\frac12$ for any $n$ is not the same as the limit being $\frac12$. An example is the sequence $\frac12 (-1)^n$.

To prove that the limit is not $\frac12$ using the definition of limits, will require showing that for some $\varepsilon > 0$, there is not an integer $N$ such that the elements past the $N$'th of the sequence are within $\varepsilon$ of $\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition should be that the limit is $3/4$. Since $3/4-1/2=1/4$, take $\varepsilon=1/8$ and try to solve the inequality
$$
\left|\frac{3n-2}{4n+1}-\frac{1}{2}\right|<\frac{1}{8}
$$
that becomes
$$
-\frac{1}{8}<\frac{2n-5}{2(4n+1)}<\frac{1}{8}
$$
Try solving these inequalities and conclude.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{3n-2}{4n+1}-\dfrac12=\dfrac{2n-5}{8n+2}.$

For $n>5$, this is more than $\dfrac {n}{9n}=\dfrac19.  $

Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{3n-2}{4n+1}$ cannot be $\dfrac{1}{2}.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|{3n-2 \over 4n+1 } - {1 \over 2} | = {2n-5 \over 8n+2} = {1 \over 4}-{11 \over 16n+4}$.
 For $n \ge 3$ we have ${1 \over 4}-{11 \over 16n+4} \ge {1 \over 26}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \ge 6$, then:

$4n >21$;

$24n -16>20n +5$;

$8(3n-2) \gt 5(4n+1);$

$a_n:= \dfrac{3n-2}{4n+1} > 5/8 >1/2;$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \ge 5/8 >1/2$.